# Constraining Constructors in a Signature

Tags: haskell

So, I'm working on a fun experiment in contextual meaning and I'm running into a wall. I'm trying to define a data type that can either be a primitive or a function that transforms from one constructor to another.

```
data WeaponPart =
    WInt Int |
    WHash (Map.Map String Int) |
    WNull |
    WTrans (WeaponPart -> WeaponPart)

instance Show WeaponPart where
    show (WInt x) = "WInt " ++ (show x)
    show (WHash x) = "WHash " ++ (show x)
    show (WTrans _) = "WTrans"
    show WNull = "WNull"

cold :: WeaponPart -> WeaponPart
cold (WInt x) = WHash (Map.singleton "frost" x)
cold (WHash x) = WHash $ Map.insertWith (+) "frost" 5 x
cold (WTrans x) = cold $ x (WInt 5)
cold (WNull) = cold $ (WInt 5)

ofTheAbyss :: WeaponPart -> WeaponPart
ofTheAbyss (WTrans x) = x (WTrans x)
```

The problems is that the signature for `ofTheAbyss` allows any WeaponPart as an argument, whereas I only want to allow WTrans-constructred arguments. You can see I've only written a pattern match for that case.

I've tried doing with with GADTs but I fear it was a rabbit hole. Could never really get them to do what I wanted. Does anyone have any ideas how I could enforce only WTrans arguments into ofTheAbyss? Or am I just completely missing something.

Thanks.

Best,
Erik

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *can* do this sort of thing with GADTs. Far be it from me to judge whether what results is a rabbit hole, but let me at least show the recipe. I'm using the new `PolyKinds` extension, but you can manage with less.

First, decide what sorts of stuff you will need, and define a datatype of those sorts.

```
data Sort = Base | Compound
```

Next, define your data indexed by their sorts. It's like building a little typed language.

```
data WeaponPart :: Sort -> * where
  WInt    :: Int ->                                   WeaponPart Base
  WHash   :: Map.Map String Int ->                    WeaponPart Base
  WNull   ::                                          WeaponPart Base
  WTrans  :: (Some WeaponPart -> Some WeaponPart) ->  WeaponPart Compound
```

You can represent ‘data of any sort’ via existential quantification, as follows:

```
data Some p where
  Wit :: p x -> Some p
```

Note that the `x` does not escape, but we can still inspect the ‘evidence’ that `x` ‘satisfies’ `p`. Note that `Some` must be a `data`type, not a `newtype` as GHC objects to existential `newtype`s.

You are now free to write `Sort`-generic operations. If you have generic inputs, you can just use polymorphism, effectively currying `Some p -> ...` as `forall x. p x -> ...`.

```
instance Show (WeaponPart x) where
  show (WInt x)    = "WInt " ++ (show x)
  show (WHash x)   = "WHash " ++ (show x)
  show (WTrans _)  = "WTrans"
  show WNull       = "WNull"
```

The existential is needed for `Sort`-generic outputs: here I use it for input and output.

```
cold :: Some WeaponPart -> Some WeaponPart
cold (Wit (WInt x))    = Wit (WHash (Map.singleton "frost" x))
cold (Wit (WHash x))   = Wit (WHash $ Map.insertWith (+) "frost" 5 x)
cold (Wit (WTrans x))  = cold $ x (Wit (WInt 5))
cold (Wit WNull)       = cold $ Wit (WInt 5)
```

I had to add the occasional touch of `Wit` about the place, but it's the same program.

Meanwhile, we can now write

```
ofTheAbyss :: WeaponPart Compound -> Some WeaponPart
ofTheAbyss (WTrans x) = x (Wit (WTrans x))
```

So it's not horrendous to work with embedded type systems. Sometimes there is a cost: if you want your embedded language to have *subsorting*, you may find you do extra computation just to change the index of some data's type, making no difference to the data themselves. If you don't need subsorting, the extra discipline can often be a real friend.

Comment: This is such a fantastic answer. I meant that the way I was using GADTs was a rabbit hole but someone, obviously, far wiser could make sense of it. And my light, someone did! Wonderful. I never would have gotten how to have it both ways, viz to have the WeaponPart Compound and the Some WeaponPart. Also, this is a great example of embedded type systems saving the day.

Comment: One last thing, I got it working which is massively exciting for me. The only thing I had to change was I had to take out the PolyKinds part and make `data Sort = Base | Compound` into just `data Base` and `dat Compound`. It kept complaining, rightfully, that Base wasn't a type constructor. Is there something I'm missing with PolyKinds? Most likely.

Comment: Ahh, I'll leave my blunder for other to learn by: I needed the DataKinds pragma, not the PolyKinds pragma. All these fancy new extensions.

Comment: Hard to see what's going on without more context. Once you have `Base` and `Compound` as types, you need `WeaponPart :: * -> *`. Indeed `Some` is not promotable, but are you using `Some` in a Kind?

Comment: It was a typo, I made the WeaponPart sig `Some -> *`. Also, I added some `Wit . WInt` , `Wit . WHash` convenience functions so now its even easier to read. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possible solution: split the data type in two. I've used names consistent with other answers to make it easy to see the parallels.

```
data WeaponPartBase
    = WInt Int
    | WHash (Map.Map String Int)
    | WNull

data WeaponPartCompound = WTrans (WeaponPart -> WeaponPart)
data WeaponPart = Base WeaponPartBase | Compound WeaponPartCompound

cold :: WeaponPart -> WeaponPart
cold (Base (WInt x)) = Base (WHash (Map.singleton "frost" x))
cold (Base (WHash x)) = Base (WHash $ Map.insertWith (+) "frost" 5 x)
cold (Base WNull) = cold (Base (WInt 5))
cold (Compound (WTrans x)) = cold (x (Base (WInt 5))

ofTheAbyss :: WeaponPartCompound -> WeaponPart
ofTheAbyss (WTrans x) = x (WCompound (WTrans x))
```

This can be made slightly more convenient by declaring a class for the basic things:

```
class Basic a where
    wint :: Int -> a
    whash :: Map.Map String Int -> a
    wnull :: a

class Compounded a where
    wtrans :: (WeaponPart -> WeaponPart) -> a

instance Basic WeaponPartBase where
    wint = WInt
    whash = WHash
    wnull = WNull

instance Basic WeaponPart where
    wint = Base . wint
    whash = Base . whash
    wnull = Base wnull

instance Compounded WeaponPartCompound where
    wtrans = WTrans

instance Compounded WeaponPartCompound where
    wtrans = Compound . wtrans
```

so that e.g. `cold` and `ofTheAbyss` could look like this instead:

```
cold' (Base (WInt x)) = whash (Map.singleton "frost" x)
cold' (Base (WHash x)) = whash $ Map.insertWith (+) "frost" 5 x
cold' (Base WNull) = cold' (wint 5)
cold' (Compound (WTrans x)) = cold' (x (wint 5))

ofTheAbyss' (WTrans x) = x (wtrans x)
```

Comment: This is also a neat solution. It is exciting how many different ways you can skin the cat as far as types go. I wonder what the advantages and disadvantages are to doing it this was vs with GADTs.

Comment: @ErikHinton The main advantage is that it's H2010, so it has a chance of working on other compilers. The main disadvantage is the extra boilerplate it requires: pattern matching is more cumbersome, and I count almost 25 lines of pure fluff defining and implementing the `Basic` and `Compounded` type classes.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to constrain your function not by type, but by constructor.  That's not a doable thing.

Indeed, it shouldn't be a doable thing -- if you're writing another function, and you have some unknown `WeaponPart`, you have to be able to pass it to `ofTheAbyss` or not -- that has to typecheck or not.

The two options I can think of are:

a) Give `ofTheAbyss` type `(WeaponPart -> WeaponPart) -> WeaponPart`, "unpacking" the constructor.

b) Have `ofTheAbyss` give a runtime error on any other constructor.

```
 ofTheAbyss :: WeaponPart -> WeaponPart
 ofTheAbyss (WTrans x) = x (WTrans x)
 ofTheAbyss _ = error "Illegal argument to ofTheAbyss was not a WTrans"
```